# phpMyAdmin export with generic field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a query which works fine in view:

```
SET @c := 0; 
SELECT ( SELECT @c := @c + 1 ) AS rowNum, email FROM HS_mailList;
```

However when I use the export function of the query result, the "rowNum" field shows NULL in the CSV.
I guess it is NULL because the SET query is not processed and my "c" var is null. I think that's it, because phpMyAdmin shows the SELECT query only, after executing the SET and SELECT combination on top. On the other hand when clicking on "show sql-querybox" it still remembers both.

In fact I have a more complex query combination but the problem is reproducible with this simple scenario. And I really need a generic iterator/counter here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does nobody have a solution for that? Anything unclear with the question?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to me to be a bug, for which I've opened a report at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12870